# Jsoup getting contents of href

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am working on a web scraper using Jsoup and want to pull a link out of a table.

This is what I'm looking at:

```
<ul class="inline-list indent>
    <li>
        ::marker
        <a href="www.linkhere.com" title="Some Text">Some Other Text</a>
        (Date & Time Stamp)
    </li>
```

I want [www.linkhere.com](http://www.linkhere.com) and Some Other Text. I have already figured out how to get Some Other Text, but I can't get [www.linkhere.com](http://www.linkhere.com).

This is what I tried:

```
Document results = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
tTable = ("li:nth-of-type(1)");

Element row : results.select("ul.indent.inline-list:nth-of-type(1)")
Element link = results.select("ul.indent.inline-list:nth-of-type(1) > a").first();

tName = row.select(tTable).text();
articleLink = link.attr("href");

System.out.println(tName);
System.out.println(articleLink);
```

This gives me the error:

> NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.jsoup.nodes.Element.attr(String)" because "llink" is null

Comment: If you browse this page with JavaScript disabled in web browser do you still see the same content on this page?

Comment: Minor change to the page but the content I am after is the same

Comment: Try to add userAgent string to your get request.

Answer (score 1):

You're using such selector:

```
"ul.indent.inline-list:nth-of-type(1) > a"
```

The first part `ul.indent.inline-list:nth-of-type(1)` selects the first `<ul>` element. The second part `> a` expects that `<a>` will be direct child of `<ul>`. That will not match what you want because there's `<li>` element between them so the solution would be to use:

```
"ul.indent.inline-list:nth-of-type(1) > li > a"
```

or if your idea was to match the first `<li>` you have to use:

```
"ul.indent.inline-list > li:nth-of-type(1) > a"
```

Comment: This was helpful, but instead of only giving me the link it gave me the entire contents from < to >. I may be able to work something out from here.

Comment: Variable `link` holds whole element "from < to >" but after that you already do `articleLink = link.attr("href");` and that's where your page address will be.